# Could anyone provide aikau form example with data loading?

Tags: javascript, alfresco-share, aikau

Aikau [example](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/aikau-tutorials-data-list-1.html) contains a `var button` which configured to show popup with form control. As I know every aikau form has a value, which can be used to prepopulate controls, but how to load value from URL?

E.g. someone push on the button, it load "somehow" data from URL, stores them into Form value and then populate one field on the form.

The key problem is what parameters to use as URL (is it `publishPayload.url`?) and what and where a topic should be set for this?

I have tried already example modification and try to add `publishPayload.url` and `setValueTopic: ALF_CREATE_FORM_DIALOG_REQUEST`, but do not see any HTTP requests with URL. If URL was wrong I can see requests with 500 or 404 codes, but even these requests are not send.

Could somebody provide an example how to do this?

**Note**

It can be just a piece of code for button and cell with value. What is the data or url it does not matter, URL can be a simple link to some NodeRef with title/name property.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want to show the dialog with the values loaded from the Repository correct? If not, please provide some more details here

Comment: Yes, exactly, but dialog should have a form for editing values.

Answer (score 0):

As with your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969496/how-add-list-headers-to-alfdocumentlistview-in-aikau/40973758) I would suggest that you work through the Aikau tutorial on GitHub (see https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/blob/develop/tutorial/chapters/About.md) I think that you'll find that it has a lot more useful information on Aikau than the official documentation - those examples are taken from old blog posts that were written **before** Aikau became a standalone project in GitHub. The examples you're looking at a very much out of date and I will try to get them removed from the official documentation.

Aikau works on a publication/subscription model. A button will be configured with a publishTopic and a publishPayload. When clicked the payload will be published on that topic. Services can be provided to subscribe to published topics and provide data.

There are lots of examples of this in both the tutorial previously referenced and in [my blog posts](https://community.alfresco.com/community/ecm/blog/authors/ddraper) on the Alfresco Community platform

Comment: I have looked into tutorial about forms, but it about something like show dialog with empty inputs and some selects which loads data array. May be I missed an idea, but I expecting show dialog with filled inputs. May be aikau forms is not for that and it is better to show dialog with several `InlineEditProperty` and update everytime when user change property? Thanks for blog post link, I'll look at this.

Comment: I've started putting together some information on forms (as video blogs) here: https://community.alfresco.com/community/ecm/blog/2016/11/28/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-aikau-forms  ... I've not done the section on form dialogs, but essentially it is the same ... there's lots of information on using form dialogs in the JSDoc (https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/DialogService.html) if you want to provide a value for the fields then just set the "value" attribute (in either the dialog request or on the form directly). InlineEditProperty is NOT a form control though.

Comment: I saw you [video](https://community.alfresco.com/videos/1087-aikau-forms-demo-part-2), when you use a button to populate form with values. How to do to so but without clicking to a button? Also as I spot, `formValue` is set before form created and should hold all form data, but it is needed to store id in formValue and then used it to load more to fill entire form.

Comment: In that example the value is being set via a **publication** . The publication can be made by any widget or service, it doesn't have to be a button. You can configure the value of each form field directly, the value of the form directly or have the value updated by publication or have it derived from the browser URL hash.  This should cover all bases - I need to understand that the user interaction as to why none of these options are sufficient - i.e. what triggers the update of values in the form?

Comment: Form showing - is a moment for request values. The main page can be opened for long time, so value in the list may be outdated. So when user click on edit she should see fresh values. So there must be something which send form update event when form is shown.

Comment: OK... (so assuming that the form is being displayed in a dialog) add a service to request the fresh data and then on receipt of the latest data have the service publish a request to the DialogService to display a form dialog with the latest values.